# set value of @ Html.EditorFor by jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-5.1

I'm trying to set some values in my form by jQuery. it works, but the values do not get in my controller.

Example:
My form

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.empresa, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control caixa-grande", id = "razaosocial-input", value="", required = "required", disabled = "disabled" } })
```

how I define the value:

```
 $("#razaosocial-input").val(dados.Razaosocial);
```

but, when i make a submit on page, i do not receive values into my controller

Comment: Is dados.Razaosocial a field in your model or where does it come from?

Comment: yes it is a field that well my model defined at the top of the page

@model ... Model name

Comment: I found that when we put the attribute disabled = "disabled" within the field, it is not passed to the controller. my solution was to remove this attribute

Comment: Oh Ok so is it working fine now?

Comment: i'ts fine for me thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to specify the id explicitly. To refer any control in Jquery you can simply use @Html.IdFor(model => model.empresa) and use this in assigning value to the control.

If you still don't get the value, try using a hidden field.